# Django: templates and iterate over dict

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a dict:

```
 >>> some_dict
{1: ['String1', 'String2', 'String3','String4' ],
 2: ['String1_2', 'String2_2', 'String3_2', 'String4_2' ],}
```

In my template i want to iterate over this dict and display values in html. So i sent this dict from view:

```
return render_to_response('tournament.html', 
        {.....
        'some_dict' : some_dict,
        'some_dict_range' : range(4),
             .....
        })
```

In tournament.html i trying to iterate over some_dict. I want to get output that should looks like:

```
'String1', 'String2', 'String3','String4'

 {% for iter1 in some_dict_range%}         
{{some_dict.0.iter1}}<br>{% endfor %}
```

And as result, i get nothing.
But when i trying to get same result without iterator:
 some_dict.0.0, some_dict.0.1, etc. i get what i need ('String1', 'String2', 'String3','String4').
And when i trying to view values of "iter1" i get the right digits:

```
 {% for iter1 in some_dict_range%}         
{{iter1}}<br>  {% endfor %}
```

0, 1, 2 ...
Why this doesn't work this way? And if i wrong in design of this, how it should looks like? I mean - what the right way to iterate over this dict and display values in html-template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't:

```
{{some_dict.0.iter1}}<br>{% endfor %}
```

Be:

```
{{some_dict.iter1.0}}<br>{% endfor %}
            ^^^^^^^
```

Else you're trying to access some_dict[0] which isn't present...

To avoid passing in the range (as I assume you're wanting to output the dict in key order), you can use the following:

```
{% for k, v in some_dict.items|sort %}
    Position {{ k }} has a first value of {{ v.0 }} and has:<br>
    {{ v|join:"<br/>" }}
    {% for item in v %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I was correct - some_dict.0.iter1. When i trying to iterate "some_dict.0.1", "some_dict.0.2" etc. - i get my values

Comment: If you access with some_dict.0.X, you dictionary must have "0" as a key because if not, you should get a KeyError raised. Is your example correct? @JonClements is right, take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables) if you don't believe us...

Comment: Yep, this is my mistake - i have a key '0', not '1'. Thx to @JonClements, his solution works perfect

Comment: And i was wrong again - solution is not perfect. What if i want to iterate over "{{ v.0 }}".  I mean i want to {{v.x}} where x - is iterator. When i try to {% for x in z%}  {{v.x}} {% endfor %} - i got nothing. (z is a range(4), for example)

Comment: Thx, this is want i search for

Comment: I don't think the "|sort" filter is working, unless I'm wrong but I tried it and it's not working